# While loop not breaking when condition is inside for loop

Tags: python, csv

I have a code that ask user to input their name. Should the name be in the csv file, it will output true and then break. If the data has no input, the loop will keep going. However, even when my output is right, it just keep looping as shown below:

```
Enter Name:Bob
true
Enter Name:
```

This is my csv data:

```
{'age': '20', 'name': 'Alice'}
{'age': '21', 'name': 'Freddie'}
{'age': '17', 'name': 'Bob'}
```

Below is my code:

```
    import  csv

filePath    =   "data.csv"
with    open(filePath)  as  csvfile:
    reader  =   csv.DictReader(csvfile)    
    was_found = False

    while True:
        nam1 = input("Enter Name:")

        for row in  reader:        

            if nam1 == row['name']:
                print("true")
                break
        if nam1 == "":
            print('Empty input, please enter again')
```

Comment: why are you using row['id'] if the key is called 'name'?

Comment: edited to name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` is scoped to the immediate outer loop. So that breaks the `for` not the `while`

Answer (score 1):

One tip for fix, use variable and check variable at end loop. Probably thats the pourpose of your variable was_found

```
import  csv

filePath    =   "data.csv"
with    open(filePath)  as  csvfile:
    reader  =   csv.DictReader(csvfile)    
    was_found = False
    have_to_break = False

    while True:
        nam1 = input("Enter Name:")

        for row in  reader:        

            if nam1 == row['id']:
                print("true")
                have_to_break = True
        if nam1 == "":
            print('Empty input, please enter again')

        if have_to_break:
            break
```

---

Im pretty sure can avoid the while True, do the for row in reader, then get then input("name")

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is return the value from a function:

```
import  csv

def get_name(reader):
    while True:
        nam1 = input("Enter Name:")

        if nam1 == "":
                print('Empty input, please enter again')
                continue

        for row in reader:
                if nam1 == row['name']:
                        print("true")
                        return nam1

filePath = "data.csv"
with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        was_found = False
        nam1 = get_name(reader)
```